# Calculation of width returns incorrect value

Tags: css

I'm trying to calculate the Width in my `css` but it seems to return the wrong value.

```
.item1 {
    width: -o-calc((50%) - (2px));
    width: -moz-calc((50%) - (2px));
    width: -webkit-calc((50%) - (2px));
    width: calc((50%) - (2px));
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
```

I've also tried the following:

```
width: calc(50% - 2px);
width: calc(~"50% - 2px");
```

They all return `width: 48%`

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

I'm testing it live and on localhost, both have the "problem" and I'm using, `Firefox`, `Chrome` and `IE`

This is what i get:

[image]

Comment: What do you expect the value to be?

Comment: what do you mean when you say it "returns" 48% - where do you see that?

Comment: @fauxserious 50% of the screen - 2px of the screen, probably. Like 50% is 20px, for example and minus 2px = 18px

Comment: You are spot on @ZeusZdravkov

Comment: @PeterHansen everything works https://jsfiddle.net/grinmax_/eo6osmsh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me you are using some kind of CSS preprocessor (LESS, SASS maybe?), which modifies the calc's argument. Otherwise following syntax should work fine:

```
width: calc(50% - 2px);
```

However in LESS for example you have to escape the argument, because LESS does its own calculations. So in LESS it would be:

```
width: ~"calc(50% - 2px)";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what is shown in the image you posted (the browser tools screenshot) isn't the CSS rule you posted above, but another rule: `.Frontpage-LeftSide .nyhead.item1`

calc rules usually are displayed in the browser tools exactly as they are written in the CSS, not as the calculated value. It seems that this rule is overwriting yours (probably due to CSS specifity).

P.S.: In case you are using `less`,  you have to write `width: ~'calc(50% - 2px)';` (corrected: added quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working fine in chrome:

```
width:calc((50% - 2px));
```

I tried to increase px values, and it reflected in pixel not on %.